# please tell me what this equation means?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm solving the past problems of real analytics for graduate school entrance examination.

In one problem, I have found

when

$$f(x) = \exp(-x-e^{-x}), F(x)=\int_\limits{-\infty}^xf(t)dt$$,

$$ \int_\limits{-\infty}^\infty F(x-b)f(x-a) = \frac{e^a}{e^a+e^b} $$

But I'm not sure what this equation means.

Where does this function come from?

Comment: Comes from? The question is simply start with given $f$, define $F$ as a integral of $f$ and then show that
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x-b)f(x-a)dx$ equals to $\frac{e^a}{e^a+e^b}$.
It is not that hard to compute $F$ from $f$ once you realize $e^{-x - e^{-x}} = (e^{-e^{-x}})'$

Comment: sorry, I'm not good at English. I want to know where we can use this formula in such as phisics or probability.
For example, Gauss Integral plays an important role in probability calculation.

Answer (score 0):

It is saying that, if you have a function $f(x)$ such that $f(x)=e^{-x-e^{-x}}$, then you can define a function $F(x)$ such that $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} f(t) dt$.

Then, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(x-b)f(x-a)(\text{with respect to }x\text{ I assume}) = \frac{e^a}{e^a+e^b}$.

So essentially, if you plug everything in and do the calculations, you end up with $\frac{e^a}{e^a+e^b}$.

I'm not sure what there is to not understand.